# query has no destination for result data i am facing this error

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 14

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings.tbl_tmp
(
    pk_sys_qr_settings_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('settings.tbl_tmp_pk_sys_qr_settings_id_seq'::regclass),
    sin_product smallint DEFAULT 0,
    vhr_key character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    vhr_value character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT tbl_tmp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (pk_sys_qr_settings_id),
    CONSTRAINT tbl_tmp_vhr_key_key UNIQUE (vhr_key)
)
```

--FUNCTION 1 - CALL FROM fn_test

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test1(sinProduct SMALLINT,
                                                                                         vhrKey VARCHAR(10), 
                                                                                        vhrValue VARCHAR(250)) 
        RETURNS VOID AS $$

BEGIN
        
        INSERT INTO settings.tbl_tmp
                (sin_product, vhr_key, vhr_value)
        VALUES
                (sinProduct, vhrKey, vhrValue);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

FUNCTION 2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test(sinProduct SMALLINT,
                                                                                         vhrKey VARCHAR(10), 
                                                                                        vhrValue VARCHAR(250)) 
                RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
        a SMALLINT;

BEGIN
        BEGIN
                SELECT * FROM fn_test1(1::SMALLINT, 'Anil-5'::VARCHAR(10), 'KV-5'::VARCHAR(250));
                
                INSERT INTO settings.tbl_tmp
                        (sin_product, vhr_key, vhr_value)
                VALUES
                        (sinProduct, vhrKey, vhrValue);
    END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

--ERROR

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_test(smallint,character varying,character varying) line 7 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 0):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL)

> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but discard the result, for example when calling a function that has side-effects but no useful result value. To do this in PL/pgSQL, use the PERFORM statement:

As the called function doesn't return anything to begin with, it's safe to use `perform`.

So use:

```
perform fn_test1(1::SMALLINT, 'Anil-5'::VARCHAR(10), 'KV-5'::VARCHAR(250));
```

Instead of `select * from fn_test(..)`

As you are using Postgres 14, you could also use a procedure in both cases, as you don't want to return a result.